# How to add untracked file in last git commit?

Tags: version-control, git-commit

I initiated git, then used following command to add all the files in commit.

```
git add *
git commit -m "Starting project modifications"
```

but still there is .htaccess file as untracked, I don't know why it was not added now I want to add it to my last commit. How can I add it without doing another commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned here:

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-commit--amend

Following is the example:

```
# Edit hello.py and main.py
git add hello.py
git commit

# Realize you forgot to add the changes from main.py
git add main.py
git commit --amend --no-edit
```